# How to subset a table by clicking in a highcharts shiny R barplot?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny

I want to show a multi bar plot in shiny, using the highcharter library (this is done).

I want also to show a table, which have the data in the plot.

My question is if it is possible to click on a bar and automatically subset the data, and show only the data which refers to the chosen column, by using shiny/R commands?

Here is my code:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

    ui <- fluidPage(
        column(width = 8,  highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px"))
      )

    server = function(input, output) {      
          output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

            hc <- highchart() %>% 
              hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
              hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
              hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
              hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
              hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE)) %>%
              hc_chart(type = "column")

              hc        
          })      
        }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to subset the data frame "a" by doing a[,column_x], where column_x is the selected bar in the highchart ("c", "d" or "e").

My question is how can I send the column chosen variable to the server.r?

**In response to K. Rohde**

Can you tell me why is this not working when I do:

```
myClickFunc <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('hcClicked', {  x: this.name, y: this.categories   });}")
```

and:

```
output$tablecontainer <- renderText({ paste( input$hcClicked$x,input$hcClicked$y) })
```

Is just printing `input$hcClicked$x` ?

I just need to capture the following actions:
- click in a bar: which name (this is ok) and which category
- click select the name in the legend
- click in the plot background

Is this possible?
Many thanks

Comment: Very well possible. Can you give a sample dataset and a shiny app, where the part you don't have is in pseudo code? This way, it'll be clear how you want your data to be shown and where and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be okay?

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, dataTableOutput("tablecontainer"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    myClickFunc <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('hcClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = myClickFunc))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  output$tablecontainer <- renderDataTable({
    if(!is.null(input$hcClicked)){
      subset(a, , c("b", input$hcClicked))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can insert any JavaScript function for click events on the graph. I'd suggest further reading [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.click) to find out which values you also can extract from the click. In this example, I just sent the name of the clicked series to `input$hcClicked` via shiny.

Comment: Can you tell me where in that link can I find how to send also the categories or if I choose the data by clicking in the legend (instead of clicking in the bar)? thanks!!

Comment: I think there is no good documentation. But [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) you can find the legend part. You could even use the same function in this case. The rest is trial and error. Possibly use `console.log(event);` to view the full information a click event holds.